# R Shiny - Using req() with isolate()

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains two `selectInput`s, `letter` and `state` (contains the abbreviated names of the US states). There is also a `uiOutput` that displays the full name of the state `input$state` below the state `selectInput`. Like so:

[image]

I would like a state's full name to be displayed only if `input$letter == b`. To do this I add the following in my `renderUI` call: `req(isolate(input$letter) == 'b')`. However, this causes the `renderUI` to never re-execute, even if the user changes `input$state` and `input$letter == b`. Nothing is rendered:

[image]

In the screenshot above, I would have expected the text 'state name: California' to be displayed because the `renderUI` still takes a dependency on the value of 'state' such that a change in `input$state` should cause the expression in `renderUI` to re-execute. So why does isolating the value of **letter** via `isolate(input$letter)` change this behaviour?

Here is the code to reproduce the above:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('letter', 'letter', letters),
    selectInput('state', 'state abbreviation', state.abb),
    uiOutput('state_full')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$state_full <- renderUI({

      # req(isolate(input$letter) == 'b')

      paste('state name:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)])

    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even isolate input$letter? A regular ifelse() should work fine?

```
library(shiny)

letters <- c("a", "b")
state.abb <- c("AL", "CA")
state.name <- c("Alabama", "California")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('letter', 'letter', letters),
    selectInput('state', 'state abbreviation', state.abb),
    uiOutput('state_full1'),
    uiOutput('state_full2'),
    uiOutput('state_full3')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$state_full1 <- renderUI({
      out <- ifelse(isolate(input$letter) == 'b',
                    paste('state name 1:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)]),
                    '')
      out
    })

    output$state_full2 <- renderUI({
      out <- dplyr::if_else(isolate(input$letter) == 'b',
                            paste('STATE NAME 2:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)]),
                            '')
      out
    })

    output$state_full3 <- renderUI({
      input$state
      out <- ifelse(isolate(input$letter) == 'b',
                    paste('state name 3:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)]),
                    '')
      out
    })

  }
)
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could use if-else but the example in my post is just contrived to illustrate my question.

Comment: hmm, I see your point. It is indeed interesting that as soon as an isolate is called, the expression does not evaluate. However, this is not always true, see if_else from dplyr. I'll leave it as a solution although I cannot precisely explain why the behavior is different in these cases

Comment: Cheers, I hope someone could shed some light on it. I've consulted the documentation for `req` to no avail.

Comment: The difference between `ifelse` and `dplyr::if_else` is caused by the fact, that `dplyr::if_else` always evaluates both values, while `ifelse` only those required. Call `ifelse(TRUE, print("true"), print("false"))`  and `dplyr::if_else(TRUE, print("true"), print("false"))` to see a difference .

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but anyway maybe somebody will find this answer useful.

The reason for this behaviour is that Shiny discovers dependencies during execution. So in the example, when `req(isolate(input$letter) == 'b')` is encountered, it stops and does not even know that it should depend on `input$state`. And since its only known dependecy - `input$letter` - is isolated, it does not have reason to execute ever again.

The fix is simple - just add `input$state` before call to `req`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('letter', 'letter', letters),
    selectInput('state', 'state abbreviation', state.abb),
    uiOutput('state_full')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$state_full <- renderUI({
      input$state
      req(isolate(input$letter) == 'b')
      
      paste('state name:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)])
      
    })
  }
)
```

The fact that Shiny discovers dependencies is even more pronounced in the following example, where again it doesn't work as desired. Since expression inside `if` is never called, there is no dependency on `input$state`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput('letter', 'letter', letters),
    selectInput('state', 'state abbreviation', state.abb),
    uiOutput('state_full')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$state_full <- renderUI({
      if (FALSE) input$state
      req(isolate(input$letter) == 'b')
      
      paste('state name:', state.name[which(state.abb == input$state)])
      
    })
  }
)
```

How reactivity works is descibed nicely in [this vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/articles/reactlog.html) to `reactlog` package. This package is great for reactivity flow visualisation, it is easy to spot while the example in question is not working. Highly recommended.